# Iterate over nested a list of objects in primefaces tabView and dataTable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I am trying to combine primefaces (v6.0) tabView and editable dataTable in jsf 2.2 framework. From reading many excellent threads from this forum, I was able to add/remove tab dynamically and implement editable table which allows add/remove a row dynamically.

However I am having a trouble to read a property "name" belongs to Hobby object. To be precise, instead of viewing a property belong to Hobby object, IDE displays properties of Person object.

I am hoping experienced JSF developers be able to find my mistake and advise me what I've done wrong and how to correct it.

FYI-The example I pasted here is water down version.

```
<p:tabView value="#{bean.people}" var="person">
    <p:tab title="#{person.name}">
        <h:panelGrid>
            <p:dataTable value="#{person.hobbies}" var="hobby">
                <p:column headerText="my hobby">
                    #{hobby.name}
                </p:column>
            </p:datatTable>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
```

Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    private List<Person> people;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        people = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // getter/setter for people
    .....
 }
```

Person model:

```
public class Person {
    private List<Hobby> hobbies;
    private String name;

    public Person() {
        hobbies = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // getter/setter for hobbies and name
    ....
 }
```

Hobby Model:

```
public class Hobby {
    private String name;

    // getter/setter for name
    ....
}
```

Comment: Care to try 6.1 (just try) and/or `rowStatePreserved="true"` on the tabview and/or datatable...

Comment: Tried with PF v6.1 but IDE still complains "unknown property name" at compile time. With PF 6.0, I added rowStatePreserved="true" on tabView which didn't recognize it but dataTable it did however recognizing property name didn't work at compile time. I observed same behavior having that attribute in PF 6.1 for the jsf project.

Comment: Please ignore everything the ide says. It blurs things (including in your feedback to us) only mention runtime errors please